# RSI output varies even with set n of days in TTR

Tags: r, quantmod, trading

I want to get RSI for some ETFs so I run the following codes

```
startDate<- '2015-09-01'
endDate<-'2015-11-01'
etfs<-c("XLE")
tickers <- get(getSymbols(etfs, from=startDate, to=endDate, auto.assign=TRUE))
RSIdataset <- RSI(Ad(tickers),n=14)
tail(RSIdataset)
```

and I got the following output:

```
                EMA
2015-10-23 58.91729
2015-10-26 51.03857
2015-10-27 47.74480
2015-10-28 53.62664
2015-10-29 54.89976
2015-10-30 56.63444
```

But when I change the start day to 2015-07-01,and keep other codes the same, I got:

```
                EMA
2015-10-23 57.69569
2015-10-26 50.29627
2015-10-27 47.17508
2015-10-28 52.91749
2015-10-29 54.16700
2015-10-30 55.87331
```

My question is why the RSI outputs are different when startDate changes even when n=14 is set, and for the same date (for example 2015-10-30). Shouldn't only the 14 days before 2015-10-30 matter? which in this case should be the same regardless what startDate is? 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The result will always be different if you change the start date and you use the default moving average (or any recursive moving average). See the *Warning* section in `?MovingAverages`:

> Some indicators (e.g. EMA, DEMA, EVWMA, etc.) are calculated using
>   the indicators' own previous values, and are therefore unstable in
>   the short-term.  As the indicator receives more data, its output
>   becomes more stable.  See example below.

The relevant example is:

```
## Example of short-term instability of EMA
## (and other indicators mentioned above)
x <- rnorm(100)
tail( EMA(x[90:100],10), 1 )
tail( EMA(x[70:100],10), 1 )
tail( EMA(x[50:100],10), 1 )
tail( EMA(x[30:100],10), 1 )
tail( EMA(x[10:100],10), 1 )
tail( EMA(x[ 1:100],10), 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, you are the best!